# How to use OpenSSL 3.0.1 to encypt/decrypt AUTHENTICATED messages (GCM/OCB) using console?

Tags: encryption, openssl, console

I am using openssl 3.0. Is it not possible? When I try the command:

> openssl enc -d -id-aes128-GCM

I get:

> enc: AEAD ciphers not supported

So how do I do it?

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021)
built on: Tue Dec 14 19:36:02 2021 UTC
platform: VC-WIN64A
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: cl /Zi /Fdossl_static.pdb /Gs0 /GF /Gy /MD /W3 /wd4090 /nologo /O2 -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC
OPENSSLDIR: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\FireDaemon SSL 3"
ENGINESDIR: "C:\Program Files\FireDaemon OpenSSL 3\lib\engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "C:\Program Files\FireDaemon OpenSSL 3\lib\ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: N/A
```

Comment: Nobody can answer this?

Answer (score 0):

GCM authenticated encryption is not supported. See https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12220